# Select a Circle in a Matrix and Link it Visually to Three Circles Below that Meet Certain Conditions

Tags: graphics, symbolic

I seek your help to derive a formula that randomly selects a small (origin) circle on a plain of hollow small circles mixed with fewer filled 50% larger circles. A selected circle located in the top horizontal third of the plain is connected sequentially to two other circles below its latitude based on minimum proximity that meets a maximum offset angle. (All circles are objects with fixed X/Y coordinates and are of the same brightness)

After the image of circles appears and remains unchanged for five seconds, the origin circle brightens, and the formula uses its X/Y location to identify another circle with the closest coordinate proximity below it and minimum offset angle. A line extends from the origin circle to the second circle, and its brightness is [image]at the moment of contact (as if pulled by gravity). This identification and connection repeats a second time with a line and a third circle. Think of the constellation Pyxis. (see image)

The third circle repeats the subroutine, seeking to connect yet again. Still, it terminates and fades the three dots and two lines simultaneously back to the original appearance unless the fourth circle identified by the subroutine is at least 50% larger than itself. In those exception cases, the dots and lines remain brightened, and a third line connects the third circle to the larger circle, which is filled and not hollow. At the moment of connection, the larger circle glows 50% brighter intensity, and the lines and circles increase their brightness to match for two seconds.

The four dots and three lines then fade away to their original appearance. After ten seconds, a new origin circle is identified, and the sequence repeats.

We can think of a shooting star that ignites several other stars as if forming a constellation.

Purpose: I wish to use the connected dots and brightness to show that people use intellect when they answer technical survey questions to derive an answer. They consider, in mere moments, many different things when making their choice, and what seems linear is spatial. The connections the mind makes often do not provide a meaningful result or satisfactory answer. But the mind keeps trying until it hits upon an answer that combines multiple points of reference. The larger, filled circle represents that, and the sequence of lines and circles brighten along with it as if finding an ah-ha moment.

To answer a survey with insight means a respondent makes answer choices using intellect based on the harmony of several thoughts. Like a constellation in the night sky, I want to create a formula that randomly selects an outlined circle representing a radio button. That radio button is only one possible choice and is confirmed by connection to other thoughts using spatial intellect.

If successful, an animated .gif file will use the series of calculations to show with simple elegance how people derive an answer choice if they have experience, expertise, and acquired skills to draw upon. What we call topical or subject matter expertise.

Like a series of connected shooting stars, this routine and subroutine will light up the computer screens of people learning to build questionnaires that offer a higher engagement intensity based on question context, sequence, and groupings. Those best practices can deliver deeper insight opportunities for researchers and moments of wonder for respondents where time stands still, the mind expands, and they exhale in micro-moments of satisfaction in the journey to reach an answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.